# Calling restful wcf web service bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, rest

My restful wcf web service is written in Visual Studio 2010.

This is the code in Service1.svc.cs

```
namespace ContactRegistration
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string JSONDataPost(Contact ContactObject)
        {   
            //code to put the data in the database goes here
            //we'll pretend it all went okay and return
            return "0|Data added okay";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in  IService1.cs

```
namespace ContactRegistration
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "/JSONDataPost",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string JSONDataPost(Contact ContactObject);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Contact
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Organisation { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public Contact(string organisation, string firstName)
        {
            this.Organisation = organisation;
            this.FirstName = firstName;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the web config.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ContactRegistration.Service1Behavior"
          name="ContactRegistration.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="ContactRegistration.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ContactRegistration.Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

When I call the web service from a web application the URI I am using is:

Uri address = new Uri("http://www.myserver/ContactRegistration/Service1.svc/JSONDataPost");

And I am getting a bad request 400 back from the server.

Is the [OperationContract] written correctly? Is there something wrong with the URITemplate? I have looked at dozens of examples today and they seem to have the URITemplate as '/NameOfMethod' which is what I have done.

EDIT: Bit of code to show the beginning of how it is called
    Uri address = new Uri("http://www.myserver/ContactRegistration/Service1.svc/JSONDataPost");

```
    // Create the web request  
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

    // Set type to POST  
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    // Create the data we want to send  
    Contact myContact = new Contact();
    myContact.Organisation = "Society of Fruit Flies";
    myContact.FirstName = "Fred";
```

Comment: What did you write in global.asax file to register routes? can you please show the code of global.asax file?

Comment: I haven't got an global.asax file. I have other web services workign okay and none of them have a global.asax file. The one above I have a slightly different version of it working but I can't add more than one method that is invoked using POST. I am just trying to get one method invoked using POST working, then, hopefully, I can put some more in.

Comment: Ok one more thing while your are creating the request. did you send the request header parameter `content-type:application/json`?

Comment: I have added a bit more code to show a bit of how it is called. But  I am sure this is not the problem. It is the calling of the method that handles the posted data that is the problem. I have GET methods working okay.